# What to do about changes in workplace lighting?

Tags: work-environment

OK, I understand some may have problems with overhead fluorescent lighting.  However, I came to work and "accommodations" had been made for an employee who is having headaches from this lighting. I am now having headaches from trying to see in the "blue" light.  It is very difficult having to continually go from this blue light area into a fluorescently lit area; it makes me kind of nauseated.  I feel like I am reading through a glass of water and nothing is focused since the filter has been added.  Although I feel bad for this other employee, what am I supposed to now do?

Comment: Related: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20988/shared-fluorescent-light-problem?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Is it possible for you to request that your desk be relocated somewhere with the regular lighting?

Comment: Do you also get that feeling when you step outside? Daylight has a strong blue component.

Comment: A simple answer here is: it sounds like the company installed type "X" lighting for Other Employee, so as to fix the "fluorescent problem" for Other Employee.  **In fact there are a *number* of bulbs available** which "fix the fluorescent problem".   Quite simply, tell them they need to try one of the "others", because brand X is causing YOU a problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can bring up your issue and see if the company can find another solution that works for everyone.

You might also consider a lamp or something that increases the lighting in your specific area, but wouldn't affect the other person.  Not sure on your industry/job as nothing is mentioned...